# PHP add arrays with duplicates

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

Right now, I have a way of merging two associative array of associative arrays with the duplicate values removed.  Here is the code:

```
//$mergedProp will output the final merged arrays
$mergedProp = array(array());
$prop1 = Array ( 
                [1] => Array ( [property_code] => CODE-01 [street] => 100 Fake Street 
                                [city] => Las Vegas [state] => NV [zip] => (no results) 
                                [county] => (no results) [id] => 6 ) 
                [2] => Array ( [property_code] => CODE-02 [street] => 200 Fake St 
                                [city] => Fake City [state] => AR [zip] => 45532 
                                [county] => Union [id] => 3 ) ) ;

$prop2 = Array ( 
                [1] => Array ( [property_code] => CODE-03 [street] => 1140 Fake Street 
                                [city] => Detroit [state] => MI [zip] => 45224 
                                [county] => Hamilton [id] => 3 ) 
                [2] => Array ( [property_code] => CODE-02 [street] => 200 Fake St 
                                [city] => Fake City [state] => AR [zip] => 45532 
                                [county] => Union [id] => 12 ) ) 

$arrayMerged = array_merge($prop1, $prop2);
$arrayUnique = array();

foreach ($arrayMerged as $row) {
  $code = $row['property_code'];
  if (!isset($arrayUnique[$code])) {
    $arrayUnique[$code] = array();
  }
    $arrayUnique[$code] = array_merge($arrayUnique[$code], $row);
}

//Sorts the array
ksort($arrayUnique);

$i = 1;
$newGrid = array();
foreach($arrayUnique as $r)
$newGrid[$i++] = $r;

$countDuplicates = count($arrayMerged) - count($newGrid);
$mergedProp = $newGrid;
```

Output for above:

```
Array ( 
    [1] => Array ([property_code] => CODE-01 [street] => 100 Fake Street 
                    [city] => Las Vegas [state] => NV [zip] => (no results) 
                    [county] => (no results) [id] => 6 ) 
    [2] => Array ([property_code] => CODE-03 [street] => 1140 Fake Street 
                    [city] => Detroit [state] => MI [zip] => 45224 
                    [county] => Hamilton [id] => 3 ) 
    [3] => Array ([property_code] => CODE-02 [street] => 200 Fake St 
                    [city] => Fake City [state] => AR [zip] => 45532 
                    [county] => Union [id] => 12 ) )
```

I want the expected output to be below instead:

```
Array ( 
    [1] => Array ([property_code] => CODE-01 [street] => 100 Fake Street 
                    [city] => Las Vegas [state] => NV [zip] => (no results) 
                    [county] => (no results) [id] => 6 ) 
    [2] => Array ([[property_code] => CODE-02 [street] => 200 Fake St 
                    [city] => Fake City [state] => AR [zip] => 45532 
                    [county] => Union [id] => 3 ) 
    [3] => Array ([property_code] => CODE-03 [street] => 1140 Fake Street 
                    [city] => Detroit [state] => MI [zip] => 45224 
                    [county] => Hamilton [id] => 3 )                    
    [4] => Array ([property_code] => CODE-02 [street] => 200 Fake St 
                    [city] => Fake City [state] => AR [zip] => 45532 
                    [county] => Union [id] => 12 ) )
```

How can I get this to keep the duplicate values instead? I basically want the output to include both $prop1 and $prop2 in 1 array.

Comment: Not sure what you mean, you already have that when you do `$arrayMerged = array_merge($prop1, $prop2);`.

Comment: Show the expected output.

Comment: @AbraCadaver I went back and included the expected output

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the PHP function `array_intersect_assoc()` is of help - it will give you the difference of the arrays.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect-assoc.php

Answer (score 0):

Fo what you've shown you just merge them as you have:

```
$arrayMerged = array_merge($prop1, $prop2);
```

And that's it.